# NOLOCK with Multithreading

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, multithreading, t-sql

I am working on a multithreaded application (C#), and 2 threads are updating a table using NOLOCK at the same time, is that a problem? To be more specific, they are both updating the same records.

Comment: Knowing when to use NOLOCK requires a deep understanding of how, when, and why SQL Server locks what. It shouldn't be used casually. If you have to ask this question, you probably shouldn't be using NOLOCK at all.

Comment: NOLOCK is to ignore the lock held by the writer when you just want to do a dirty read!

Comment: If I knew about nolock I wouldn't be asking :) This is how the application was implemented at my job and I'm debugging the problem. They use nolock in every query irregardless. We have almost 800 stored procs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is "it depends".

NOLOCK allows 'dirty reads'.  This means that *within a transaction*, you may see uncommitted data from another transaction. If you have multiple threads updating the same row in the same table, you may see the modified value of data that the other thread touched, before that thread commits it's transaction.

For example, take the table account_balances, defined as (account_num int, balance decimal(12,2)).  Let's assume the following happens:

// precondition, account #1 has a balance of 10.00

1. Thread #1 starts a transaction, decrements account #1 by 10
2. Thread #2 starts a transaction, attempts to read the balance of account #1.  It reads a balance of 0.
3. Thread #2 decrements the account by $5, and issues an overdraft to the customer (their balance is -5)
4. Thread #1 rolls back it's transaction
5. Thread #2 commits it's transaction

// The account balance is now -5, even though it should be 5.

What you *won't* see is some form of inconsistent data within a field- the nolock hint isn't like running multi-threaded code without a lock- individual writes are still atomic.

Comment: Even under `read uncommitted`, writers block writers. Therefore, thread 2 wouldn't be able to update the row until thread 1's transaction completed. Other than that, this is spot on.

Comment: So if I'm expecting a 1 in the column and it shows up as 2, it might be thread racing rather than having anything to do with nolock?

Comment: Again, it depends. If you have 2 threads performing reads and subsequent writes within the same transaction then it does have to do with the nolock, in the sense that if you were using read_committed locking, you wouldn't be able to read dirty writes.

Comment: Makes sense too. So if i read data before it was committed and modify it afterwards that will be problem.

Answer (score 2):

It means that you can get records that are in an 'erroneous' state.

For example...

- Process1 is deleting a block of data
- Process2 is reading an overlapping block of data, WITH NOLOCK

In an ideal situation, either all the records being deleted by Process1 are either present or deleted.  Because Process2 is using NOLOCK, it may read ***some*** of the records Process1 is deleting, but not others because they've already gone.

The same goes for INSERTS and UPDATES.  You may simply read records that are only Part of the way through being altered in some way.

Whether this is a problem depends on your data, your design, etc.

A search engine won't care if this happens.  A Bank dealing with financial transcations will.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the same record simultaneously, even if using NOLOCK hint.

**BUT**

You can bring the data into inconsistent state.

AFAIK - it is not possible to apply this hint to target table of update.

And - this hint allows you to **read** uncommitted data, **not overwrite** them.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful how you use this.  Potential data inconsistencies.

If one query is
     set colA = "newColANewvalue" from tableA with (nolock) where colA = "colAOldvalue"

And another query is
     set colC = "colCnewValue" from tableA with (nolock) where colA = "colAOldvalue"

You can end up with with colC = "colCnewValue" and colA = "newColANewvalue" on the same record. If that is not a problem then OK.

What is driving this?  Are you getting performance issues with rowlock or pagelock?